# Links in <angle-brackets> don't show up

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown, markdown-rendering

Links in `<>` do not appear in questions.
Here is an example:

`<meta.stackexchange.com>` is above. It is invisible.

Comment: The brackets will be treated as an HTML tag, but it isn't valid, so it doesn't show up

Comment: It's because it's not a valid link without the `http://`

Comment: See also [Please block posts containing unsupported HTML](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300679) on meta.SO.

Comment: Please do not remove the question once you get answer. Thanks. (this just renders the answers useless and makes the whole question pointless to begin with)

Comment: @ShadowWizard OK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The renderer treats them as 'tag' when it sees the texts in the  angle brackets.

But, if you want to **just display** angle brackets then you can get them with `&lt;` and `&gt;`

For example:

`&lt;meta.stackexchange.com&gt;`

will display:

<meta.stackexchange.com>

And, if you want angle brackets along with **linkable URL** then:

`[&lt;http://meta.stackexchange.com&gt;](http://meta.stackexchange.com)`

will display:

[<http://meta.stackexchange.com>](http://meta.stackexchange.com)

Or, this one if you **don't want angle brackets** in clickable URL link:

`&lt;[http://meta.stackexchange.com](http://meta.stackexchange.com)&gt;`

will display:

<http://meta.stackexchange.com>

Comment: You are right! This seems to be something that may trip new/inexperienced users up.

Answer (score 7):

You didn't post a link. You posted a domain.

```
<http://example.com>
```

will show as http://example.com because that's a link given the necessary `http://` prefix.

Posting just the domain means you're running foul of the [whitelisted HTML tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites).